# How to rename a multi-root workspace inside vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How or can i rename a multi-root folder without renaming the actual folder and changing the path? I basically need it to have some random settings files in a nicely named folder like "Settings"?

So it looks like this:

Workspace Name

Python   (Folder with custom name - path does not matter)

Settings (Folder with custom name - path does matter)

or

Settings

Folder with settings files (Folder with custom name - path does matter)

Answer (score 2):

in the `.code-workspace` file you can set a `name` for each folder that is part of the Multi Root Workspace. You have to it with vi or Notepad++ or other editor.

Comment: Thanks, thats what i wanted.

Comment: I have a new question now. How can i link a file in a folder without puting it in a folder?

Comment: @patrick40 on linux use a symbolic link

Comment: That worked. In windows its: mklink /j "path to junction link" "path to target link". It might be a bit confusing with what the link says, but it still works when editing the files.